# function undefined error on show hide a div

Tags: javascript

i am trying to show and hide a div on click of a checkbox but it shows an error of checktwelve or checkten is undefined.please help me out here

```
    function hided2(checkten) {
        if (checkten.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("d2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("d1").style.display = 'none';
            checktwelve.checked = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("d2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("d1").style.display = 'block';
            checktwelve.checked = true;
        }
    }
    function hided1(checktwelve) {
        if (checktwelve.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("d1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("d2").style.display = 'none';
            checkten.checked = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("d1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("d2").style.display = 'block';
            checkten.checked = true;
        }
    }
```

and i made Onclick="hided1(checktwelve)" on checktwelve and likewise on other 
checkten and checktwelve are id of checkboxes

Comment: What are checktwelve or checkten?

Comment: Post the markup also. The function doesn't show anything wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to toggle visibility of d1 if clicked on checkten and that of d2 if clicked on checktwelve?

Answer (score 0):

> checktwelve or checkten is undefined

You haven't defined these variables.

```
Onclick="hided1(checktwelve)"
```

tries to find `checktwelve` in global scope and can't find it.

Comment: Those are parameters to the functions.

Comment: where and how to define

Comment: @JeevanJose variables with these names are not defined, so it's undefined argument to the function being called

Comment: @SumitSharma It depends on what you want. Dynamically calculate or they are fixed. By looking at your code, I don't think you need parameters to your functions at all. Checkten and checktwelve look like they refer to certain buttons. You could have variables linking to these buttons and use them iostead.

Comment: checkten and checktwelve are two checkboxes and i want to show and hide div having ids d1 and d2.

Comment: That's what I thought, you need to remove these parameters from functions. Before functions declare variables: `var checkten = document.getElementById("yourChecktenId"); var checktwelve = document.getElementById("yourChecktwelveId"); `